# 400 Bad Request - facebook page tab

Tags: facebook, http-status-code-400

I created app in facebook by this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/
It's only page tab, so the page is loaded by iFrame, but facebook return this error:

"**400 Bad Request**

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand."
Any ideas ?

Comment: Provide more details, like what calls are you making? Etc.

Comment: I added Page Tab in Fb developers > apps.
Page Tab URL and Secure Page Tab URL is set.
But app on the fan page doesnt works. I see only 400 Bad Request etc.....

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. It's becouse there is a POST request for your page instead of GET. You can solve it (well... kind of) by putting this PHP code in the very beggining of your page:

```
if ($_POST) {
   header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   exit(); 
}
```